# Detect changes in a deeply nested object to modify NgStyle from a service using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an HTML element that I need to modify a style attribute using `[ngStyle]`. To do this, I created a component variable called `templateStyle` and set it to a value within an object provided by a service I created called `componentStyles` that looks like this:

**base.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  // returns a nested object of styles from my database
  var componentStyles = await this.styleService.componentStyles$.pipe(first()).toPromise();

  // I check to see if the style I need to set exists on the object, if it does, I add it
  this.templateStyle = {
    'min-height': componentStyles.customAttributes.sectionHeight != null ? `${componentStyles.customAttributes.sectionHeight}px` : null;
  }
}
```

This `templateStyle` variable is assigned to my `div` like so:

```
<div [ngStyle]="templateStyle"></div>
```

---

**Now here's the issue:**

A user can modify the `sectionHeight` property using a slider within a popup. So in my popup component, I access the `styleService.componentStyles$` to get a reference to the style object and then I can modify the `sectionHeight` based on the value of the slider like so:

**popup.component.ts** in `ngOnInit()`

```
// call the same service to get reference to styles
var componentStyles = await this.styleService.componentStyles$.pipe(first()).toPromise();

this.slider.subscribe((change) => {
  // emits current value of slider (from 1 to 100)
  // this is the same property that is being assigned in the templateStyle variable in the
  // base component
  componentStyles.customAttributes.sectionHeight = change.detail.value;
})
```

Since `componentStyles` is an object and passed by reference, the actual data value does indeed change, BUT it doesn't cause Angular to run change detection in the base component since a new object of `templateStyle` is not reassigned, (only the value of `componentStyles.customAttributes.sectionHeight` is being changed). This results in the `[ngStyle]` object not updating and the `min-height` attribute not changing.

Since my current context is within the popup, how can I force the `templateStyle` object back in my base component to check for changes? I understand that I can do:

`this.templateStyle = Object.assign({}, this.templateStyle)`, but the slider is in the **popup.component.ts** and does not have access to the `templateStyle` variable in the base component.

What is the best way to go about this?

---

**Temporary Solution**

The easy route would be to simply assign the css directly from the service object like so:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{
    'min-height': `${componentStyles.customAttributes.sectionHeight}px`
}"
```

This **works**, but it makes my HTML look sloppy and I'd rather set it to a component variable instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally consider this a case of having a 'style state'. The approach I would use is instead of having these components access in what appears to be an object from the service (since I don't see .subscribe()) is to instead use a SUBJECT (rxjs) to manage your styles, and in particular a [BehaviorSubject](https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/).

What you would do in that case is create a BehaviorSubject in your service, give it an initial value from some database call, and in both your popup and your base component subscribe to it. When you want to emit the change caused by your popup you would use subjectname.next(styleObject). If it's a simple modification of the existing style object you could keep a local copy in your popup.ts file to reference and change before emitting.

If your template still doesn't update when this occurs, go ahead and do manual changedetection: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Simply inject the service and call cdref.detectChanges() where the change happens

Happy coding!

Comment: Hey @iamaword ! So yes, the `styleService.componentStyles$` is already an observable set to a `BehaviorSubject` within my `styleService`. The thing is, I can't just set my `[NgStyle]` to that subject because I need to format the object to replace styles like `min-height` and append a `px` string to the end of the property etc. In short, I need to take an object and convert the object to css syntax

Comment: If you need to modify the observable before to get it you could create a wrapper property in your own service and "pipe , map" it into a new form.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shared or common services to communicate between components. That's useful specially when child components are deeply nested. I like to use the `BehaviorSubject` as a mean to communicate.

In the CommonService, setup a `BehaviorSubject` Subject/Observable:

```
export class CommonService {

  private heightBehavior = new BehaviorSubject<number>(20);
  height$ = this.heightBehavior.asObservable();

  setHeight(value: number) {
    this.heightBehavior.next(value);
  }
}
```

In the ChildComponent, inject the service and use it to set and emit the new values, in this case the height when the slider's value changes:

```
export class ChildComponent {

  constructor(private commonService: CommonService) { }

  changeValue(value: number) {
    this.commonService.setHeight(value);
  }
}
```

In the parent component inject the service and subscribe to the exposed Observable. (You could also do that in the ngOnInit but for simplicity let's put it in the constructor):

```
export class AppComponent {
  divStyle = { height: "20px" };

  constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
    this.commonService.height$.subscribe(val => 
      this.divStyle = { height: val + "px" }
    )
  }
}
```

In the template, as you suggested, you can use the ngStyle to set the height:

```
<div [ngStyle]="divStyle"></div>
```

Check this Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kynfwa

Comment: why not "set Height(value:int)"  instead?  setters and getters are awesome.